# Joining 4 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question regarding joining 4 tables. This is my query.

```
SELECT  
    a.pick_id, a.Serial_No, a.Work_Ord_No, a.Lot_No, 
    a.Product_no, a.Plan_Qty, a.Machine_no, a.shift, a.Scan_dt, 
    b.Trml_code,
    case when c.Wire_Type is null then '-' else c.Wire_Type +' '+ c.Wire_Size+' '+c.Wire_Color end as Wire,
    case when d.Mtrl_code is null then '-' else d.Mtrl_code end as Material
FROM
    pickMaster a 
JOIN
    pickTerminal b ON b.id = a.id 
JOIN
    pickWire c ON c.id = a.id 
JOIN
    pickInserting d ON d.id = a.id
```

This is the data for 4 table before I join them.

[image]

And this is the result after I join them.

[image]

The problem is after I join the 4 table the result show 4 row with the same data on material and wire. How to solve this?. Any idea?.

Comment: The 4 rows actually are not the same.  They all have different `Trml_code`/`Material` values.  What is your expected output?

Comment: I expect the output will be two row only with different trml_code and material

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: @AmarulSamsudin What's the status now ?

Comment: does `pickTerminal` and `pickInserting` have any connection?
And what does the ID represent?

Comment: @Sameer still pending

Comment: @domiSchenk ID is the FK

Comment: There are 4 different rows.  Which 2 would you want?

Answer (score 0):

Because, You have double-IDs (*103*) for the last two tables.

Comment: Any idea how to join?

Comment: @AmarulSamsudin I don't think the problem is related to the joininig technique but the data(repeating ID values).

Comment: @Sameer  a Demo with some sample values may be good to test for your code.

Comment: @AdamCalvetBohl but the values for `Trml_code` and `Mtrl_Code` do not match.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan this is the reason I say they must be "filtered" out...   Only joining gives double results 'cause last two tables have duplicated id's, as you said. He should filter by these fields or rethink the structure, in my opinion.

Comment: @Sameer No. He gets multiple results because he has duplicateid's, as Barbaros said.  You can join "infinite" tables and still have only one row, if you do right.

Comment: I am not so good in database structure. That is why i ask for you guys opinion on how do i structure by database to get the output that I want.

Comment: @AmarulSamsudin, I can't help you if you don't give MUCH more info about your project. And this is not the right place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Cartesian product between `pickTerminal` and `pickInserting`.
You need to connect this two tables somehow.

**Example!! This is the only attribute i see as common?!**

```
SELECT  
    a.pick_id, a.Serial_No, a.Work_Ord_No, a.Lot_No, 
    a.Product_no, a.Plan_Qty, a.Machine_no, a.shift, a.Scan_dt, 
    b.Trml_code,
    case when c.Wire_Type is null then '-' else c.Wire_Type +' '+ c.Wire_Size+' '+c.Wire_Color end as Wire,
    case when d.Mtrl_code is null then '-' else d.Mtrl_code end as Material
FROM
    pickMaster a 
JOIN
    pickTerminal b ON b.id = a.id 
JOIN
    pickWire c ON c.id = a.id 
JOIN
    pickInserting d ON d.id = a.id
    and d.mtrl_side = b.Trml_side <-- add this
```

but without more context its hard to tell how you can archive this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don`t need any information from the 3rd or 4th tables except the distinct material/ terminal codes , you can use left join instead of join for the last two joins.